# Rails 4 How to display belongs_to record in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

so please bear with me :)

***group.rb***

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

***category.rb***

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
  validates :content, :presence => true
  validates :group_id, :presence => true
end
```

***app/views/categories/index.html.erb***

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= category.id %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to category.name, admin_category_path(category) %>
    </td>
    <td><%= ***[GROUP WHERE CURRENT CATEGORY BELONGS TO]*** %></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to admin_category_path(category), class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to edit_admin_category_path(category), class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to admin_category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-xs" do %>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

***My question is:*** how to display a group belongs_to this categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, just write:

```
<td><%= category.group %></td>
```

Or

```
<td><%= category.group.name %></td>
```

One good idea is to define the function "to_s" for your classes.
For example

**group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_s
    name
  end
```

That way Rails will automatically output the name for the group when printing the group meaning that

```
<td><%= category.group %></td>
```

and

```
<td><%= category.group.name %></td>
```

Will output the same information.

Comment: I try that one before, here is my controller code:
@categories = Category.all. but not working

Comment: Sorry, its working now, I forgot to add group_id to strong parameters, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `<%= category.group.name %>` to display a group belongs_to this categories.